# Why isn't Switch assigning a value using Set?

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to do an approval workflow by just changing the fields rather than via Flow. In that, I want to have some variables to pass into my fields. Somehow, my Set is not working. In the first one, it does get "Submitted" from the record, but it seems unable to assign a value to newStatus based on that.

RequisitionGallery draws from a Sharepoint list.

```
Set (currentStatus, RequisitionGallery.Selected.Status);
Set (newStatus, Switch ( currentStatus,
"Draft", "Approved by Hiring Manager",
"Submitted", "Approved by Hiring Manager",
"Approved by Hiring Manager", "Approved by Hiring Manager's Supervisor",
"Approved by Hiring Manager's Supervisor", "Approved by Vice President/Managing Director",
"Approved by Vice President/Managing Director", "Approved by USG COO",
"Approved by USG COO", "Approved by SVP/GXT",
"Approved by SVP/GXT", "Approved by Director, Corporate Recruitment",
"Fully Approved"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get your code working with a few semantic tweaks and formatting.

Set the `OnSelect` property of Gallery icon to:

```
Set(varCurrentStatus, ThisItem.status);
Set(varNewStatus, 
    Switch(
        varCurrentStatus,
        "Draft", "Approved by Hiring Manager",
        "Submitted", "Approved by Hiring Manager",
        "Approved by Hiring Manager", "Approved by Hiring Manager's Supervisor",
        "Approved by Hiring Manager's Supervisor", "Approved by Vice President/Managing Director",
        "Approved by Vice President/Managing Director", "Approved by USG COO",
        "Approved by USG COO", "Approved by SVP/GXT",
        "Approved by SVP/GXT", "Approved by Director, Corporate Recruitment",
        "Fully Approved"
    )
);
```

**Works like a charm:**

[image]

Comment: Odd, but it works there. Not sure what was up with my button that it wouldn't set the newStatus. Maybe it was that the variable needed to be instantiated in the Gallery's OnSelect before opening the screen on which the button sat. I'm sure it will make sense some day! Thank you!